# javah: Error: cannot access android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I know there are similar questions here already, but none of them seem to help. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

I'm trying to create a JNI file and folder in Android Studio, following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFtxo7rr2HQ but no matter what I do I keep getting errors. I've got it to a point where it says:

```
    Error: cannot access android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
      class file for android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity not found
```

Here is the command I am giving it:

```
  javah -d jni -classpath ~/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar:../../build/intermediates/classes/debug com.example.ndktest.MainActivity
```

I have tried adding these two libraries, figuring that this would resolve my issue, but no luck:

```
    javah -d jni -classpath ~/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar:~/android-support-v7-appcompat-master/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar:~/android-support-v7-appcompat-master/libs/android-support-v4.jar:../../build/intermediates/classes/debug com.example.ndktest.MainActivity
```

This gives me the same error. I'm at a loss for what I can try next to make this work. Eventually my task is to integrate an application into an android build rom, but I need to understand Android.mk files first, and for that I need to understand how to use the NDK to use preexisting C++ code. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this problem is change the **AppCompatActivity** to **Activity**, then you are good to go.

You are quit careful, since you change the semicolon to colon already. I make a mistake for that.